# Removing p tag if it contains certain class

Tags: jquery

```
 <div id="info-leftside">
                <div class="label-container" id="name-label"><p class="info-field-label">name</p><p class="error">error</p></div>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="field"/>
                <div class="label-container" id="email-label"><p class="info-field-label">email</p></div>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="field"/>
                <div class="label-container" id="phone-label"><p class="info-field-label">phone</p><p class="error">error</p></div>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="field"/>
                <div class="label-container" id="address1-label"><p class="info-field-label">address (line 1)</p></div>
                <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" class="field"/>
                <div class="label-container" id="address2-label"><p class="info-field-label">address (line 2)</p></div>
                <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" class="field"/>
                  <div class="label-container" id="city-label"><p class="info-field-label">city</p></div>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="field"/>

</div>
```

What would be the most efficient way of removing the p tags that contain the class 'error'? Should I use hasClass on the class label-container? But then how do I remove if true?

Comment: why not use simple selector way?(eg : $(".label-container p.error").remove())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `$('.error').remove()`?

or to be more specific `$('p.error').remove()` provided if you are using same class for some other elements.

Comment: @Crontab Oh I was updating while u left this comment :)

Comment: doesn't get any more simple than this. +1